# AngularJs Search form with WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to angularjs so I may be taking the wrong approach but here is my situation.  I have an MVC3 app but I am only using Mvc to serve up a "layout" page and the script and css files.  In that view I have a ng-view tag.  Here is my routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/templates/search.html', controller: 'SearchController' }).
        when('/Search', { templateUrl: '/templates/searchResults.html', controller: 'SearchController' });
```

So initially the search.html template is going to load which is nothing but a form and Search button.  The user enters whatever form data they want to search by and click "Search" which is tied to a function $scope.search that gets the form data and call WebApi to get the results.  The function returns a promise, and .then I want to assign the results to the $scope and then load the searchResults.html template by calling `$location.path("/Search");` The problem is when that is called it reloads the controller and the $scope is wiped out.

I want to do this without using the MVC framework.  I know angular takes a new way of thinking and I think my problem lies there.  Can anyone guide me to where I should be going with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call the `$location.path("/Search");`.

Hide the tag in which you need to show the search results using `ng-hide` and show it when the promise is executed.